# Jquery Scripts does not work on Partial View's first time load but work with Ajax call MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a problem in loading scripts on first time load of view in ASP.NET MVC, the scripts are present on Partial View but these scripts are not called when page is being loaded first time.

But when I append the same partial view second time using Ajax call, the scripts load perfect on the view and components present earlier on the view appended by the partial view also work perfect.

Here I little further discuss my problem in detail that when same scripts I call via _Layout view, then these scripts does not work on partial view, and When I put the same scripts on Partial view also then the problem arises of scripts called two times and my functions are called twice.Actually I am using **SignalR** scripts and due to 2 times referencing of scripts one time on _layout View and 2nd on Partial view my SignalR functions are called twice and my all code logic ruins.

This is my Home view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartKids.Lib.Core.ViewModels.FileMediaAlbumsVM>


@{
      ViewBag.Title = "Home";
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
<div class="profile-body">
    @*@Html.Partial("ModalMessages")*@
    <div class="row">
            @Html.Partial("_Messages")
    </div>
    <div class="row infinite-scroll">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="clientScreenWidth" id="clientScreenWidth" />
        @Html.Partial("_AlbumRow", Model)
    </div>
    <div id="loading" class="text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts{

<script src="~/Scripts/infiniteScroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var moreRowsUrl = "/Album/Home"; //the URL to your ActionMethod
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);

</script>

        }
```

and This is my Main _Layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Smart Kids</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin'>
<!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
<link href="~/Content/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/headers/header-default.css" />

<!-- CSS Customization -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/custom.css" />

<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #122;
    }
</style>   



 @RenderSection("metaTags", false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--=== End Header ===-->
        <div class="container" id="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>     
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/albumSignalR.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Now I have no scripts in Partial view and this is my Partial View code:

```
<div class="widget-extra margin-bottom-15">
            <div class="timeline">                    
                <ul class="timeline-list">                        
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("HomeAlbum", "Album", new { aId = item.AlbumId })">
                            <picture class="thumbnail img-responsive">

                                <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="@Url.Content(filepath_mobile), @Url.Content(filepath_mobile) 2x">
                                <source srcset="@Url.Content(filepath_small), @Url.Content(filepath_small) 2x">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(filepath_mobile)" alt="@item.Title">
                            </picture>
                        </a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Kindly suggest me some solution to this, what I am doing wrong or what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the order in which the scripts get executed. But you would need to post  your code...

Comment: Scripts should never be in partial views. Move them to the main view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I move scripts to main view, then scripts are never called. neither on the partial view and nor the view.what could be the issue in that case?

Comment: You need to show your code (we cannot guess what is wrong)

Comment: yes sure I show my code

Comment: whatever scripts you are using put path of those scripts in bundle config then render your script using bundle config like you did for modernizr .

Comment: it does not work in that way either, I put the scripts in bundle and tested but still failure

Answer (score 0):

> why dont you move the closing script
>   tag within   the closing }

```
@section scripts{ 
<script src="~/Scripts/infiniteScroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//$(function () {
//    $("div#loading").hide();
//});
var moreRowsUrl = "/Album/Home"; //the URL to your ActionMethod
$(window).scroll(scrollHandler);

 </script>
}
```